How Are The Initial Value of Conditional Variance Calculated in rugarch Package?
I am trying to verify the calculations of my zero-mean GARCH(1,1) model using the rugarch library. At first I thought the initial first value of the conditional variance were the same values as the unconditional variance (which the arch package in python use) as there is no past return, nor past variance to calculate it from.
But as I rechecked for the first initial values of the conditional variance using garch_fit@fit$var, it is different from the unconditional variance.
I have tried to manually calculate the unconditional variance using a calculator and it gave me the same output as uncvariance(garch_fit), which is not the initial first value of the conditional variance from the model. So if the GARCH process is not initialized by the unconditional variance, how is the first value calculated?
Here are my codes for the specs:
garch_spec <- ugarchspec(
  mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(0, 0), include.mean = FALSE),  # No ARMA terms, zero mean
  variance.model = list(model = "sGARCH", garchOrder = c(1, 1)),  # GARCH(1, 1)
  distribution.model = "norm"  # Normal distribution
)
garch_fit <- ugarchfit(
  spec = garch_spec,
  data = data$log_return_pct,
  solver = "hybrid",
  out.sample = 83
)

and the difference between the first initial variance
> uncvariance(garch_fit)
[1] 0.5865156
> garch_fit@fit$var[1]
[1] 0.5869211

